# how to assign MouseMove, MouseDown and MouseClick functions to several controls creates dynamiqumement?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with event management (`MouseMove`, `MouseDown` and `MouseClick`). I created the label dynamically (this number of labels depend on the result of a SQL query) the pobléme I want when i move this labels created dynamically i want start MouseMove function ... here is the code I used:

```
int count;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cnx.Open();
cmd.Connection = cnx;

string mois = cmbMat.SelectedValue.ToString();

cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Table Where Month(Date)=" + mois;
count = (int)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
int i =count;
Label Jalon;
for(i=0,i<count,i++)
{
    Jalons = new Label();
    this.Jalons.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MouseClickLab);
    this.Jalons.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MouseDownLab);
    this.Jalons.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MouseMoveLab);
    this.Controls.Add(Jalons);
}
```

so how I will specify the label in the function mousemoveLab,MouseDownLab and MouseMoveLab?? i thinking for this :

```
private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Text = e.Location.X + ":" + e.Location.Y;
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.ActiveControl.Left = e.X + this.ActiveControl.Left -                  MouseDownLocation.X;
        this.ActiveControl.Top = e.Y + this.ActiveControl.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        this.ActiveControl.Height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sender that you receive in the event to identify the label.

```
private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    Label label = (Label)sender;

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        label.Left = e.X + label.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        label.Top = e.Y + label.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```